# How to manage sub-category as main category as well?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, products-management, category-products

I am running a furniture shop for a client and need to sort out the categories.

I want users to be able to search by room (Living room, Bedroom, Kitchen ect...) But also want them to be able to search via furniture type (Bed, Table, Chair ect...)

I need it to display the furniture type in layered navigation when viewing the rooms category and display the rooms category when viewing the furniture type category.

Can't think of a way of doing this other than having it as follows...

- Living Room

  - Tables
  - Chairs
- Bedroom

  - Tables
  - Chairs

However this means that users can't access all the chairs at one time...  How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Catalog->Manage Categories->Choose category-> Inside “Category Products Tab”** 
 Add whatever products you want to show.